# Zend DB using a column for both Where and Order clause

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework

I like to use a column in Zend both in the Where clause as well as the Order:

```
$select = $this->select();
$select = $select->where('year = ?', $year)
                 ->where('order != ?', 0)
                 ->order('order');
$rows = $this->fetchAll($select);
```

But when I do this, I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order != 0) ORDER BY `order` ASC' at line 1

Why??!

Comment: When you remove the `->order()`-call, does it work?

Answer (score 3):

You must put the column name `order` into ticks since it is a reserved word of SQL syntax.
Even better never name your columns like keywords in SQL, so rename your column `order` to something else.